# C++ XML and base64 data generation slow

Tags: c++, xml, performance, base64

In a C++ application I need to generate base64 data and put it into XML. Data comes from a 3rd party library via a static function (`int writeData(uint8_t* data, int data_size)`).

The code runs on a Raspberry Pi (ARM1176).

Sometimes this 3rd party library calls `writeData` frequently, in every 5-6ms. (and it does not really respect delays)

I'm creating XMLs with [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) which is:

> an attempt to create the fastest XML parser possible

And for Base64 generation I'm using [Boost](https://www.boost.org/).

Because the first part of the XML itself is static I wrote those parts only once at initialization:

```
xml_document<> XMLDocument;
xml_node<>* XMLNode; //its value will be changed in writeData fn
xml_attribute<>* XMLAttr; //its value will be changed in writeData fn
string XMLOutput; //final xml string
string Base64Data; //base64 data holder

void initXML() {
  // create declaration
  xml_node<>* decl = XMLDocument.allocate_node(node_declaration);
  decl->append_attribute(XMLDocument.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
  decl->append_attribute(XMLDocument.allocate_attribute("encoding", "utf-8"));
  XMLDocument.append_node(decl);

  // create variable attribute
  XMLAttr = XMLDocument.allocate_attribute("id", 0);

  // create variable node
  XMLNode = XMLDocument.allocate_node(node_element, "main");
  XMLNode->append_attribute(XMLAttr);
  XMLNode->value(data.c_str());

  XMLDocument.append_node(XMLNode);
}
```

So in `writeData` I will only need to generate the base64 and put it into this XML structure - as fast as possible.

`XMLOutput` will hold the final string in XML format.

```
using namespace boost::archive::iterators;
using It = base64_from_binary<transform_width<uint8_t*, 6, 8>>;

int writeData(uint8_t* data, int data_size) {
  XMLOutput.clear();
  Base64Data = std::string(It(data), It(data + data_size)).append((3 - data_size % 3) % 3, '=');
  XMLAttr->value("newValue");
  XMLNode->value(Base64Data.c_str());
  print(back_inserter(XMLOutput), XMLDocument, print_no_indenting);

  return data_size;
}
```

**The problem is that this current writeData implementation takes too much time and cause high CPU usage.**

With empty `writeData`, it's executed around 200 times per second. However with this implementation it is executed only around 40 times per second.

How can I make faster the base64 and xml generation? (Base64 was needed because XML does not allow binary data inside. I don't want to stick to base64 if a reasonable and faster method exists).

C++ standard I'm using is ISO C++11 (-std=c++0x), compiler optimalization is off (-O0), debugging is max (-g3).

Comment: *compiler optimalization is off* - that's your problem... There is also reallocation of `string` buffer on each call and suspicious `print` invocation.

Comment: `print` is a rapidxml method here, it cannot be avoided as it is the one who creates the final xml string.

Comment: string reallocation: good point, but I didn't figured it yet how can I avoid that.

Comment: Turning on compiler optimization takes it up to 98 times per second. I'm wondering if it could be optimized even more.

Comment: How large is your base64 data?

Comment: raw data is 4096 bytes

Answer (score 1):

I see three small efficiency improvements:

- `reserve` enough space in your target string up front for the Base64 string including padding;
- `reserve` enough space in your `XMLOutput` for the final XML string;
- Use `XMLNode->value(Base64Data.c_str(), Base64Data.size())` to avoid an extra `strlen` call.